# How to config Vite build output that can run with <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Tags: shopify, vite

How can I config Vite build to output with script **type="text/javascript"**

I'm using Vite 2.7.2, when finished building the code in HTML output the script tag as follow

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.0c37d7b4.js"></script>
```

What I want is

```
<script type="text/javascript" crossorigin src="/assets/index.0c37d7b4.js"></script>
```

The code run fine with **type="module"** but when I manually replace it with **type="text/javascript"** the code break and output following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
```

Here is the original code before building

```
const elements = {
  root: document.querySelector('#root'),
};
elements.root.innerHTML = `Loading...`;
```

The reason I want the type to be **type="text/javascript"** because Shopify platform only accept script with type "text/javascript"